# Quarz retry / misfire

Tags: quartz, retry-logic

I have an understanding problem concerning Quartz:
if an exception occurs in execute (...) of the job - does that count as misfire or do i have to worry about a retry myself in this case?
Or in other words: I want to have a (simple) trigger for only one successful shot but if the execution fails a retry until success for three times.
How do I configure that?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I solved this and it was very important for me:
to handle this I have to prepare the JobExecutionException like this
jobExecutionException.setRefireImmediately(true);
for example
or solve it in any other way - individually
the thing to notice is, that the offered misfire-behaviour handles if
the scheduler is not able to schedule the start of the job/matching the
point as configured by the trigger.